# GAE, from tastypie import api causes "NotImplementedError: Only tempfile.TemporaryFile is available for use"

Tags: django, google-app-engine, tastypie

Need some help on this Tastypie error on Google app engine. The code worked fine on GAE for long time. Suddendly, it has some weird error when import tastypie api.

Not sure if due to mismatch of django, tastypie and python version.

----my_api.py----

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf import urls
from tastypie import api    >>>> cause problem <<<<
```

----error log file----

....

```
File .../third_party/py/tastypie/api.py", line 11, in <module>
from tastypie.resources import Resource
File .../third_party/py/tastypie/resources.py", line 22, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import GeometryField


File ...python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ctypes/util.py", line 90, in _findLib_gccfdout, ccout = tempfile.mkstemp()
File ...python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 45, in   PlaceHolder
raise NotImplementedError("Only tempfile.TemporaryFile is available for  use")
NotImplementedError: Only tempfile.TemporaryFile is available for use
```

Comment: Could you post the whole traceback - it seems that some lines are missing from the middle

Comment: The problem is gone today. I did not make any change to my code. I spend whole whole day on this. 1) GAE fixed it? If that's the case, it's not acceptable the way GAE is managed for my production server.  2) My web server has time sensitive data?  I will have to think/look.